# Stargazer tables: Math Annotations

Tags: r, stargazer

The stargazer package for R has two arguments, covariate.labels and column.labels, that customize table text.

I want to use Greeks or math expressions in these arguments.  Ive tried standard syntax for latex text and Ive tried stand R expressions, as shown below:

```
covariate.labels = c($\beta_{0}$, $\beta_{1}$)
covariate.labels = c(expression(beta[0]), expression(beta[1]))
```

Ive also tried variations on the above and Im yet to achieve the basic math symbol annotations.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

`covariate.labels` needs to be a character vector. Remember that you need to escape backslashes with another backslash in an R string though.

```
stargazer(mtcars[,1:2],covariate.labels=c("$\\beta_{0}$", "$\\beta_{1}$"))

% Table created by stargazer v.4.5.3 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Feb 05, 2014 - 16:21:19
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lccccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Statistic & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{St. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max} \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
$\beta_{0}$ & 32 & 20.091 & 6.027 & 10.400 & 33.900 \\ 
$\beta_{1}$ & 32 & 6.188 & 1.786 & 4 & 8 \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\normalsize 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are doing this but with `type = "html"`, you can [use html tags to modify table elements](http://www.jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer/#use-html-tags-to-modify-table-elements). This worked for me:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, mtcars)

stargazer(model,
         covariate.labels = c("<p>&beta;<sub>0</sub></p>",
                              "<p>&beta;<sub>1</sub></p>"))

% Table created by stargazer v.5.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: mar., ago. 15, 2017 - 09:55:31 a. m.
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & mpg \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 <p>&beta;<sub>0</sub></p> & $-$2.876$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.322) \\ 
  & \\ 
 <p>&beta;<sub>1</sub></p> & 37.885$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (2.074) \\ 
  & \\ 
 \hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 Observations & 32 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.726 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.717 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 3.206 (df = 30) \\ 
F Statistic & 79.561$^{***}$ (df = 1; 30) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Which ends up looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwoyR.png)